# Reports Generation for Web Based Application Using Selenium Tool

Tags: unit-testing, junit, selenium-rc, testng

Currently we are generating HTML Reports for  Automation, but those reports are not good enough to explain number of scenario which we cover in Automation, Is there anything we can use with Selenium to generate a proper reports which can give a complete overview and can easily understand by anyone

First Thing we can show a complete pie charts which cover number of test case passed and Failed.
Second thing we  can show, what are test cases are there in this build.

Answer (score 2):

You may also checkout the page
 http://seleniumtesting-nx.blogspot.de/2012/03/testng-xslt-report-generation.html
I found it useful. :)

Answer (score 0):

It's easy to write your own TestNG reporter, look up IReporter in the doc.